# java image output error

Tags: java, eclipse

this application doesn't really serve a purpose but i'm using to as practice as i'm fairly newbie lol. I have made it work successfully spam saving a screenshot to a set location but now when i attempted to add a feature to use the console to set the output location the application seems to just end after i enter 1 or 0.

```
public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            HeadlessException, AWTException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String login = System.getenv().get("USERNAME");
        String desk = "/Desktop/lol/";
        int num = 0;
        int numd = 100000;
        int dd = 10000000;
        int dl = 999999;
        String start = null;
        String location = "C:/users/" + login + desk + num + ".png";
        int loc = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter a new custom location to print image");
        // the if statment is used to make it possible to change the image
        // location output
        loc = scan.nextInt();
        if (loc == (1)) {
            location = scan.nextLine();
            start = scan.nextLine();
        } else {
            location = "C:/users/" + login + desk + num + ".png";
            start = scan.nextLine();
        }
        while (start.equals("start")) {
            num++;
            numd--;
            dd++;
            dl--;
            BufferedImage image = new Robot()
                .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                    .getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(location));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:/users/" + login + desk
                + num + ".png"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:/users/" + login + desk
                + numd + ".png"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:/users/" + login + desk
                + dd + ".png"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:/users/" + login + desk
                + dl + ".png"));
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.pack();
            window.setSize(1920, 1080);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your immediate problem can be solved with:

```
    loc = scan.nextInt();
    String discard = scan.nextLine(); // add this as the new line stays in input
    if (loc == 1) {
        location = scan.nextLine();
        start = scan.nextLine();
    } else {
        location = "C:/users/" + login + desk + num + ".png";
        start = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Now the way you do it spams infinite windows - is that what you want ?

Comment: yeah lol its sort of a prank to distract the person from the screenshots being created,Now only if i could use the screenshots being created onto the Jframe.

Comment: So this solves your problem ? If yes accept my answer

Comment: But yes thank you @Mr_and_Mrs_D that solved the issue i was experiencing

Comment: Thanks - that's what you should do in general here when an answer solves your problem - go and see if your other question is answered and choose best answer